# Visual Studio Load Testing

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I've created a Web Performance Test in Visual Studio 2013.  The test logs into my website, basically adds some items to my database, and then sends an email out to the user.  Everything works great.

Now, when I run this same performance test as part of a Load Test, it appears to run fine with no errors, but there is no data in the database and no emails are sent.

So, does the Load Test actually update the database or send emails?  Or does it someone need to be enabled?

Again, it works great as a Web Performance Test, just missing something as a Load Test and I'm not sure what.

Thanks in advance,

Randy

Comment: When a web test passes with green-ticks on every request it does not mean that it worked. I suggest doing something to the web test to make it fail. E.g. set the expected response to the last request to be 500. Then when the web test is run within a load test you will get the test run logs. They will allow you to see the requests and responses and see what happened as the test runs. I suggest doing a run with at most 10 users and enough time for 5 executions per user. Then look at several of the run logs.

Comment: (See an answer to [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50bc12a1-617d-484d-b035-f8aeb0a9f270/get-individual-test-iteration-results-from-a-load-test?forum=vstest) about how to access the test logs.)